# Getting bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails to use font-awesome instead of bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, bootstrap-wysihtml5

After searching on the Internet for an hour trying to find a simple, how-to write up of how to substitute bootstrap glphicons for font-awesome when using the bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails gem, I came up empty handed.  I did find a variety of issues with loading the fonts.

Does anyone have a current write up on how to do this?

Alternatively, perhaps you can help with getting my rails sass app to use both font-awesome and bootstrap icons in parallel so that bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails works.   Right now, I am getting an error: "RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff")" (localhost - with or without precompiled assets) which many folks have struggled with.  I tried the many suggestions [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/395), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978525/file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-bootstrap-wysihtml5) and others to no avail.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: To be clear, I am able to use font-awesome just fine.  I am able to use BS (not glphicons) just fine.  I am not able to use the wysithtml5 (which uses BS glphicons) at the same time.